# How to suspend/resume processing of a Lua command

Tags: c, lua

I'm writing a client that can talk to multiple servers and processes user commands on `stdin` or eventually from a file using Lua.  The server is a custom application, so I'm handling all the communication back in `C` where all the code for the protocol has already been written.  Here's a bit of pseudo-code of what I have now:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  /* setup fd list, vars, etc */
  ...
  while (1) {
    /* process list of file descriptors to create read/write fd sets */
    ...
    select(max, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, NULL);
    for each file descriptor {
      if (read fd is set) {
        read data into a buffer
        if (current fd is stdin)
          process_stdin()
        else if (current fd is from server connection)
          process_remote()
      }
      if (write fd is set) {
        write data on non-blocking fd
      }
    }
  }
}

int process_stdin() {
  luaL_loadbuffer(L, stdin_buffer, len, "stdin");
  lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
}

int process_remote() {
  parse buffer into message from remote system
  if message is complete, call Lua with either a new message notification or resume
}
```

So here's my problem: If the user on `stdin` types something like `wait_for_remote_message(xyz)`, how do I stop at that point, return from the `lua_pcall` and go into the `select` loop to wait for more data?  And then, how would `process_remote` resume the Lua command from that point forward?

I can imagine a solution involving pthreads, but that feels like overkill for this application and introduces a lot of extra complexity.

I can also imagine a solution where the `while(1)/select` loop is moved into a function and from the `wait_for_remote_message(xyz)` I jump back to `C` and call this function with `stdin` added to some kind of exclusion list.

Are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use for Lua coroutines, where you can call yield to suspend execution, and then resume later.

Check out http://www.lua.org/pil/9.html for details

You might do something like

```
int process_stdin() {
    lua_State coroutine =  lua_newthread(L);

    luaL_loadbuffer(coroutine, stdin_buffer, len, "stdin");
    if (lua_resume(coroutine, 0) == LUA_YIELD) {
     // store coroutine somewhere global
    }
}

int process_remote() {
    // parse buffer into message from remote system

    // push the message onto the Lua stack
    lua_resume(coroutine, 1);
}
```

Comment: Am I allowed to yield from a `lua_pcall`?  Or is there a way to do a `lua_resume` after the `luaL_loadbuffer` instead of the `lua_pcall`?  I agree coroutines sounds like a perfect match, but I'm missing the way I link in the processing of `stdin` with the coroutine.

Comment: Hmm, after looking through the docs some more, it looks like the answer to my second question is going to be yes since `luaL_loadbuffer` is returning a function.  Let me do a little testing to see if I can get this to work.  Thanks Wossname.